# Is this an efficient way of bulk inserting using Dapper?

Tags: c#, .net, database, insert, dapper

Is this an efficient way of bulk inserting using Dapper?

Also, is this more efficient than creating a stored procedure and passing models to it?

Is this an efficient way of bulk inserting using Dapper?

Also, is this more efficient than creating a stored procedure and passing models to it?

```
category = new Category
           {
               Name = "category",
               Description = "description",
               Created = null,
               LastModified = null,
               CategoryPictures = new CategoryPicture[]
               {
                    new CategoryPicture
                    {
                        CategoryId = 3,
                        PictureId = 2,
                        Picture = new Picture
                        {
                            Url = "newUrl"
                        }
                    },
                      new CategoryPicture
                    {
                        CategoryId = 3,
                        PictureId = 2,
                        Picture = new Picture
                        {
                            Url = "url"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

string sql = @"INSERT INTO Categories(Name, Description, Created, LastModified)
               VALUES(@Name, @Description, @Created, @LastModified)";

await conn.ExecuteAsync(sql, new
            {
                category.Name,
                category.Description,
                category.Created,
                category.LastModified
            });

string catPicInsert = @"INSERT INTO CategoryPictures(fk_CategoryId, fk_PictureId)
                        VALUES(@CategoryId, @PictureId)";

await conn.ExecuteAsync(catPicInsert, category.CategoryPictures);

string PicInsert = @"INSERT INTO Pictures(Url)
                     VALUES(@Url)";

await conn.ExecuteAsync(PicInsert, category.CategoryPictures.Select(x => x.Picture).ToList());
```

Comment: No it's gonna be dog slow, use `SqlBulkCopy` or a table parameter instead.

Comment: You don't specify which database you are using. If you are using PostgreSQL, then consider using npgsql. That library has a BulkCopy feature which you can use with c#. If not, I'd consider using stored procedure. If you keep it inside c#, you need to use transactions. you snippet as written will autocommit at every executeAsync. That is very slow.

Comment: @EdMendez I'm using sql server

Answer (score 3):

It won't be hugely slow, but it won't be anywhere near as fast as a bulk copy. Options, assuming SQL Server:

- it is possible to use TVPs with Dapper, but the only *convenient* way to do this is by packing your input data into a `DataTable`; there are examples of TVP usage in the Dapper repo, or I can knock one out, but they're inconvenient because you need to declare the parameter type at the server
- you can use `SqlBulkCopy` to throw data into the database independent of Dapper; FastMember has `ObjectReader` that can construct an `IDataReader` over a typed sequence, suitable for use with`SqlBulkCopy`

If you're not using SQL Server, you'll need to look at vendor-specific options for your RDBMS.

Comment: FastMember's ObjectReader is my goto for SqlBulkCopy scenarios, it's incredibly useful.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you use Bulk Insert function of SQL.
It can be combined with Dapper as well.
I was looking for the example like this for a long time, and finally found the pieces of solution, and combined them in one place.
You can see the example in my repo:
https://github.com/ayrat162/BulkInsert

It uses Dapper.Contrib, FastMember, and SqlBulkCopy for uploading large chunks of data to MS SQL Server.

Comment: I tested your demo - it inserts as fast as 400,000 recs/sec!! It's 3 times faster than commercial Dapper.Plus! Impressive, thanks for solution. Test system: Win7 x64/MS SQL 2014

Answer (score 1):

I've changed it up into using multiple sprocs for each table.

```
    public async Task<bool> CreateCategoryAsync(Category category)
    {
        category = new Category
        {
            Name = "category",
            Description = "description",
            Created = null,
            LastModified = null,
            CategoryPictures = new CategoryPicture[]
              {
                    new CategoryPicture
                    {
                        CategoryId = 1,
                        PictureId = 2,
                        Picture = new Picture
                        {
                            Url = "newUrl"
                        }
                    },
                      new CategoryPicture
                    {
                        CategoryId = 2,
                        PictureId = 2,
                        Picture = new Picture
                        {
                            Url = "url"
                        }
                    }
              }
        };

        string sql = @"EXEC Categories_Insert @Categories; 
                       EXEC CategoryPictures_Insert @CategoryPictures; 
                       EXEC Pictures_Insert @Pictures";


        var spParams = new DynamicParameters(new
        {
            Categories = category.ToDataTable().AsTableValuedParameter("CategoriesType"),

            CategoryPictures = category.CategoryPictures.ListToDataTable()
                                                        .AsTableValuedParameter("CategoryPictureType"),

            Pictures = category.CategoryPictures.Select(x => x.Picture)
                                                        .ListToDataTable()
                                                        .AsTableValuedParameter("PicturesType")
        });

        using (var conn = SqlConnection())
        {
            using (var res = await conn.QueryMultipleAsync(sql, spParams))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the extension class with generic methods that i created for mapping objects or a list of objects into Datatable

```
public static class DataTableExtensions
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert an IEnumerable into a Datatable
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="listToDataTable"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DataTable ListToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> listToDataTable)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        AddToDataTableColumns<T>(dataTable);

        foreach (var item in listToDataTable)
        {
            AddDataTableRows(dataTable, item);

        }

        return dataTable;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Comvert a Type of Class to DataTable
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this T obj) where T : class
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        AddToDataTableColumns<T>(dataTable);

        AddDataTableRows(dataTable, obj);

        return dataTable;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add values from of Type T to a given Datatable columns
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Extract values from</typeparam>
    /// <param name="dataTable">The datatable to add column values into</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static DataTable AddToDataTableColumns<T>(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        try
        {
            PropertyInfo[] FilteredProps = GetFilteredProperties(typeof(T));

            for (int i = 0; i < FilteredProps.Length; i++)
            {
                PropertyInfo prop = FilteredProps[i];
                Type type = prop.PropertyType;

                dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) ?? type);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new InfrastructuredException(ex.StackTrace);
        }

        return dataTable;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add values from of Type T to a given Datatable Rows
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Extract values from</typeparam>
    /// <param name="dataTable">The datatable to add Row values into</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static DataTable AddDataTableRows<T>(DataTable dataTable, T obj)
    {
        try
        {
            PropertyInfo[] FilteredProps = GetFilteredProperties(typeof(T));

            object[] values = new object[FilteredProps.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = FilteredProps[i].GetValue(obj);
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new InfrastructuredException(ex.StackTrace);
        }


        return dataTable;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Return an array of Filterered Properties of a Type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <returns>Properties that are filtered by Type</returns>
    private static PropertyInfo[] GetFilteredProperties(Type type)
    {
        return type.GetProperties()
                    .Where(p => p.Name != "Id" && !p.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseEntity)) && !p.PropertyType.IsInterface)
                    .ToArray();
    }

}
```